# Drag and Drop issue while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

A layout that I am working on is attached here, but I have two problems:

1. While dragging the draggable item's position is not right.
2. I would like to make sure that upon drop the previous content is overriden, which I did and is working fine, but I have three dropables and whenever I drop on any of the dropables the dropped element in the other dropables is also replaced by latest, but I want to restrict the override to the item I was dropping at.

Plesae view the layout in screens bigger than 1024px.

If anyone can let me know, it would be amazing.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rajat_jain/pen/EepMBr

Comment: Grammar and format was improved.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code to the question.

Comment: @LajosArpad Cannot paste the whole code here, due to character limits, I've cleaned up the code in codepen link, if you could check now.

Comment: I have answered your question, but in the future try to share the relevant part of the code in the question as well, it was unnecessarily difficult to answer without knowing where to look at. Also, offsite links may get broken in time. Finally, a question should consist of a single question. You asked two questions as a question. You should have asked them as separate questions.

Comment: @LajosArpad, thanks for the tips, I'll keep those in mind for the next ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positioning problem comes from the values you have provided to `translateX` and `translateY`, respectively, here:

```
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers.ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(1).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(2).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(75%) translateY(-25%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(3).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(135%) translateY(-100%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(4).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(275%) translateY(-80%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(5).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(380%) translateY(47%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(6).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(492%) translateY(-20%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(7).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(92%) translateY(72%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(8).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(202%) translateY(40%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(9).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(302%) translateY(-20%)
  }
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(10).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(402%) translateY(90%)
  }
```

If you find their right value, then their positioning will be okay. I did not do this for all of them, but I will give you an example:

```
  .problemanserwrapper .problemanswers:nth-child(3).ui-draggable-dragging {
    transform: rotate(0) translateX(75%) translateY(-50%)
  }
```

The cause of the second problem is that you use a single variable called `pastDraggable` to track the history of all the three boxes. Whenever you put an item into a box, the value of `pastDraggable` will be changed. Whenever you put your next item, the value of `pastDraggable` will be the previous one, independently of its box, it will be removed from the box and the new value will override. You should declare `pastDraggable` as an array:

```
var pastDraggable = ["", "", ""];
```

and in the `drop` event, find out the index:

```
        var droppableIndex = 0;
        if ($(this).hasClass("droppable2")) droppableIndex = 1;
        else if ($(this).hasClass("droppable3")) droppableIndex = 2;
```

and at every usage of `pastDraggable`, make sure you use it along with its index, as `pastDraggable[droppableIndex]`.

Comment: Hello @Lajos, yes the second issue was resolved yesterday, and the problem was just as you described, using the same variable. Thank you.
But for the first problem, is there no other way except finding the current transform value, like taking the mousemove position and giving it to the draggable's position?

Comment: @RajatJain it might be possible, but the code is far too long for the purpose of giving free help, without knowing where to look inside it. Here we want to help you, but we will not allocate too much time. You should check in your browser which CSS rules contribute to the positions of your elements and where the problem is coming from. It will be a long analysis which will not be done here by answerers. The best is to do a quick fix according to my answer so your soft will work well and if you are not satisfied with the solution, then find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I understand it is time-consuming. However I found the root cause and solved it, the problem was the transform's translate property I was using to place elements, that was effecting position even when the items were being dragged, so I changed it up to use margins for the positioning and it's working great now. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @RajatJain you are welcome and I am glad your problem is solved.